# How can $\sin(90) = 1$?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I know this question has been asked before, but the answers don't really make intuitive sense.

> As angle $\theta$ approaches $90$ degrees, how can $\sin(90) = 1$ if there IS NO triangle?

This breaks all other ratios as well, because the other ratios can be written in the form of $\sin(\theta)$ as well.

A simple answer (if it exists) s'il vous plait.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The trigonometric functions are defined also outside the ranges we have in a triangle.

Comment: I find it's more useful and intuitive to think of $(sin(\theta), cos(\theta))$ as the $(x,y)$ point on the unit circle at angle $\theta$ against the horizontal.

Comment: Indeed, as triangle sides usually don't have negative lengths either, and yet sine and cosine can go negative. It may have originated as ratios in a right-triangle, but more useful when generalised to all angles.

Comment: @Vercingetorix isn't that usually $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$?

Comment: @Randall It is yeah. Just a typo. I'm not allowed to edit comments after posting them apparently :(

Answer (score 4):

If you a want to know how is $\sin(90^{\circ})=1$ from a triangle's point of view, well you can take any right angled triangle and fix the base length. Now increase the perpendicular side. You will see that as you increase the side, length of hypotenuse also increases. If the angle opposite to the perpendicular side is $\theta$, so now as you increased that side, notice that $\theta \to 90^{\circ}$, and the length of hypotenuse tends to the length of the perpendicular side. So, $\sin \theta = \dfrac{\text{Perpendicular}}{\text{Hypotenuse}} \to 1 $ as $\theta \to 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: True.. but, theta will not reach 90. This breaks Pythagoras' Theorem. If length extends to infinity then sure. But at that point pythagoras' Theorem breaks. So we have to assume that it never reaches 90. This is case similar to 0.99999999999.... = 1. It's NOT 1, but the difference is very much negligible.

Comment: That's why others have given the answers that really show you why is $\sin(90^{\circ})=1$. What I have shown to you is according to your wish from a triangle's perspective. This shows that $\sin(89.99\cdots)$ tends to $1$. Of course, you can't apply pythagoras theorem here as a triangle with two $90$ degree angles cannot form. It is a limiting case. For seeing, why it is exactly $1$, see the approach using unit circle that others have shown.

Answer (score 1):

To spell out @Vercingetorix's point:

The radius-$1$ circle centred on the origin in $2$ dimensions has equation $x^2+y^2=1$ by the Pythagorean theorem. (If it's not obvious this holds when $x$ and/or $y$ is negative, reflect in an axis so they're not, and note $(-u)^2=u^2$.)

For acute $\theta$, a right-angled triangle exists containing $\theta$ with vertices $(0,\,0),(\cos\theta,\,0),\,(\cos\theta,\,\sin\theta)$. The first and last of these are the ends of the hypotenuse, which is a radius, and the side adjacent to $\theta$ is the radius ending in $(1,\,0)$. Rotating $\theta$ anticlockwise from that radius gives the hypotenuse.

Any radius can be used the same way, even if the resulting angle isn't acute, and it meets the circle at $(\cos\theta,\,\sin\theta)$. This defines the trigonometric functions for any $\theta\in\Bbb R$. The choice $\theta=90^\circ$ gets you to the radius ending at $(0,\,1)$, so $\cos90^\circ=0,\,\sin90^\circ=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x$ is the $y$ coordinate on the unit circle and $\cos x$ is the $x$ coordinate. If you use your intuition a $90$ degrees $\cos x$ must be $0$ because its a straight line up and $\sin x$ must be $1$.

Comment: The problem is, this argument if valid should be applicable. Yet, when applied to triangles; it seems to break a fundamental part of geometry. Perhaps the problem is with me.. I think math needs to not only be accurate, but to be true as well. I hate that 0.9999999999999999999... is = 1 That doesn't make sense

Comment: I think you need to review your calculus, $0.99\dots=1$: $$9\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{10})^{n}=1$$, In other words: $0.99\dots=1$ Also this is an expansion of the sine function so it doesn't have to be applicable on triangles.

Comment: @Camus You say it doesn't make sense, but there is a whole wikipedia page on it. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...#:~:text=9%2C%20among%20other%20ways%20denotes,number%20is%20equal%20to%201.)

Comment: Well, my bad. I didn't mean that it literally doesn't make sense. We still didn't go deep into calculus yet in school. My point is, 0.999... uses the concept of infinity. I found that problematic because of my definition of what 1 is. It's all cleared up now though, thanks